# Fullpage.js Slide vertical on scroll

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

What im trying to achive is to when i have slides inside section to slide vertically (not horizontally). Is there any way how can i do this? This is my fiddle how it looks now:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/slicedtoad/4o3qLr8j/8/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=4o3qLr8j

So how can i change them all to vertical?

Answer (score 0):

You can not change them. It is not an easy task.

But, what you can do is simulate the column behavior by using the extension [Interlocked Slides](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/).

This way when you slide to the right, slides in other sections will move accordingly. 
You would only have to prevent the right or left scrolling in the sections under the current one to make the user believe they are actually in a column structure.

Of course, this requires a bit of extra coding using callback such as `onLeave` and `afterLoad` from your side (to prevent the right and left scrolling as well as to hide the control arrows). But it is in fact possible :)